# How to manually call UITableView's titleForHeaderInSection method?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates, title, sections

Pretty simple question, but I just can't get it to work right. I need to be able to access the string header value of a section when a cell within that section is clicked.

My initial attempts haven't been working:

```
[tableView titleForHeaderInSection:1];
```

The reason I thought that would work is because I am also using this:

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Which works fine. I'm implementing the delegate, but I still get the warning that UITableView may not respond to titleForHeaderInSection. And then it crashes because of an unrecognized selector.

All I need to do is pass the string value of the cell title, and the section title into the next view.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`titleForHeaderInSection` is the method of `UITableViewDataSource` protocol which is implemented by the client class not `UITabelView`.

So you can't call `titleForHeaderInSection` on your `UITableView` instance.

Comment: That worked great! I didn't know that method was part of a different protocol, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `titleForHeaderInSection` from `UITableViewController` and `UITableView`: you just need to follow the objects chain.

**Example starting at the view controller:**

```swift
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    func titleForHeaderInSection(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> String? {
        if let tableView = self.tableView {
            if let dataSource = tableView.dataSource {
                if dataSource.respondsToSelector("tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:") {
                    return dataSource.tableView!(tableView,
                                                 titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.row)
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

`[tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];`

Comment: assuming that your data source doesn't change from before the time that your table starts loading and you ask for this data, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Calling manually `titleForHeaderInSection` did not work for me.

But a simple `[tableView reloadData]` did the trick.

Hope this helps